# Parameterize parameters?

Tags: system-verilog, iverilog

I would like to parameterize `localparam` parameters.

My module definition:

```
module native  #(
  parameter SIM_ONLY = 0,
  parameter FREQ = 500
)(
  ...
);
```

I have lots of instantiations using the same `localparam parameter A`.

```
if (FREQ == 550) begin
  localparam A = 987;
end else begin
  localparam A = 122;
end

AA #(
   .A_VALUE  (A),
) AA_inst (
 ...
);
```

But that isn't allowed in the specification, is there a different proper way to do it?

/!\ The `A` value is a magic number, not something that can be calculated from `FREQ`.

I've tried:

```
if (FREQ == 550) begin
  shortreal A = 987;
end else begin
  shortreal A = 122;
end
```

but I get `The expression for a parameter actual associated with the parameter name... must be constant.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the conditional operator `?:`

```
localparam A = (FREQ==550) 987 : 122;
```

You can also put more complicated expressions into a constant function

```
localparam A = some_function(FREQ);

function int some_function(int F);
   case(F)
     550: return 987;
     123: return 456;
     default: return 122;
   endcase
endfunction
```